# Building several projects sumultaneously by CruiseControl.NET

Tags: configuration, cruisecontrol.net

Our CruiseControl.NET server is configured to build 5 different projects. Is it possible to configure CruiseControl.NET in such way that maximum 2 projects are built simultaneously? It is easy to limit it to build only one project at a time by putting all projects in the same <queue>, but I can't find how to limit number of simultaneously building projects to arbitrary number.

We are using CruiseControl.NET 1.4.4.

Comment: i don't have an answer, but i am curious as to why you want to do that?

Comment: I assume you are want dynamic queue, not hand-code two queues, thus if A & B need to build they do if A & B & C need to build C waits, but if B & C or A & C need to build they do at the same time, thus A & C are not in the same queue.

Comment: @bumperbox: Some of the projects are "heavy" and they should be built alone, some of the projects are lighter and 2 of them can be run simultaneously to make use of 4 cores of build server.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you want to sequence the build order of projects , you can do it with project dependency triggers..